# Volatility matrix understanding

Tags: finance, mathematical-modeling, hidden-markov-models

I have problem to understand volatility matrix on page 9 section 2.3 The Yield-Adjustment Term in the following article: [Volatility matrix in Nelson-Siegel](https://www.frbsf.org/economic-research/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/wp07-20bk.pdf). It is volatility matrix in AFNS model. Why does volatility matrix in this general form:
$\Sigma =\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sigma _{1,1} & \sigma _{1,2} & \sigma _{1,3}\\ 
\sigma _{2,1} & \sigma _{2,2} & \sigma _{2,3} \\ 
\sigma _{3,1} & \sigma _{3,2} & \sigma _{3,3}
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$
can be changed to triangular volatility matrix: $\Sigma =\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
\sigma _{1,1} & 0 & 0\\ 
\sigma _{2,1} & \sigma _{2,2} & 0 \\ 
\sigma _{3,1} & \sigma _{3,2} & \sigma _{3,3}
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$

I understand how yield-adjustment term is derived, but then I do not understand simplification for volatility matrix.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: When asking a question about a tiny bit in a 46 page paper you could do us the favour to mention the page on which they make that claim. I am having doubts that they claim it in this form BTW.

Comment: @KurtG. I wrote that it is on page 9 but never mind

Comment: Yes. Sorry I was blind. The authors don't say that one can change every $3\times 3$-volatility matrix to triangular. I think they are trying to find those volatilities from data, and they are saying that in their model they are only able to find six and not nine volatilities. This puts the restriction on the $\Sigma$ matrices that they should reasonably consider.